# Difference between numpy.dot and a.dot(b)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Is there a difference between

```
import numpy as np
np.dot(a,b)
```

and

```
a.dot(b)
```

internally?
I wasn't able to find any documentation on the latter method.

Comment: [Here's the documentation you couldn't find](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html), which mostly boils down to "equivalent to `np.dot`". The method only exists on arrays, not arbitrary array-likes, though.

Comment: `np.dot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` works,  Generally if there's both a function and method version, the function delegates to the method after a bit of argument massaging. In the `dot` case both are compiled so it's harder to study the details.  Use whichever form looks prettier in your code.

Comment: If you plan to use some sophisticated external libs with your numpy-code, consider using the np.dot() variant. This is at least true for [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md): ```Similarly, we don't support the syntax A.dot(B); use the equivalent np.dot(A, B) instead. The reason we don't support the first way is that subclassing ndarray raises a host of issues. As another consequence of not subclassing ndarray, some subclass checks can break, like isinstance(x, np.ndarray) can return False.```

Comment: @user2357112: Does anyone want to formulate an answer, so that the question stays no longer unanswered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `a` is an array, they're equivalent. The docs you couldn't find for the `dot` method are [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html), and they boil down to "see [`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)".

If `type(a) is not numpy.ndarray`, then `numpy.dot` will convert `a` to an array and use the array for the multiplication, while `a.dot` will do whatever `a`'s type says it does, or raise an AttributeError if `a` doesn't have a `dot` method.

Comment: so for `A.shape = (47,1), B.shape = (47,3)` and `A.dot(B)` that gives a `C` that is shape `(47,3)` by transposing A to do the dot product?

Comment: @mLstudent33: What? No. `A.dot(B)` gives an error in that case.

Comment: `error.shape = (100,1)` and `X.shape = (100,3)`, I am able to do `error.dot(X)` check `ln[10]` and `ln[11]` here:  https://github.com/suraggupta/coursera-machine-learning-solutions-python/blob/master/Exercise2/exercise2.ipynb

Comment: @mLstudent33: There's no `error` or `error.dot(X)` in those cells or anywhere in that notebook. (Also, it's `In`, as in "input", not `ln`.)

Comment: I apologize, the error is `(h-y)` both `h` and `y` are vectors shape `(100, 1)` which results in a vector of shape `(100,1)`.  `X` is of shape `(100, 3)`.  So it must transpose automatically when necessary?  I noticed `np.dot` seems to do so as I tried executing with `.T` and without and got the same result.

Comment: @mLstudent33: Those are 1D arrays, not 2D. There is no second dimension of length 1.

Comment: Got it thanks!  I was thinking of math where dot product even for a 1D array is explicit with regards to transpose.