# matrices are not aligned while trying to use np.dot in numpy arrays in jupyter notebook

Tags: arrays, numpy

The below code I am trying to do in jupyter notebook and in this i am not possible to do dot product of two matrices

```
# creating random array
 
np.random.seed(0)
sales_amounts = np.random.randint(20 , size=(5,3))
sales_amounts


# creating weekly sales dataframe

weekly_sales = pd.DataFrame(sales_amounts, index =["Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri"],
                          columns =["Almond Butter","Peanut Butter","Cashew Butter"])
weekly_sales

# Create the price array
    
    prices = np.array([10,8,12])
    prices

    prices.shape


#Create butter prices dataframe

    butter_prices = pd.DataFrame(prices.reshape(1,3), index=["price"],columns= ["Almond  Butter","Peanut_Butter","Cashew Butter"])
    butter_prices


# shapes not aligned lets transpose

    total_sales = prices.dot(sales_amounts.T)
    total_sales


    #creating daily sales
  
butter_prices.shape,weekly_sales.shape


daily_sales = butter_prices.dot(weekly_sales.T)
```

After executing the above code in jupyter notebook
it shows as error: matrices are not aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6obg.png)

**Solution**:

`np.dot(butter_prices, weekly_sales.T)` works

**Explanation**:

Read the first answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517281/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-a-dotb) that explains why this is happening.